# Change costum View color between colors animated

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view

I have a custom View which I draw an arc that represents the progress of an event like passed time between two dates. It looks like this:

[image]

I want to change stroke color of the arc between my arc coolor and red as time passes.

I have tried following but it doesn't work:

```
remainingTimeProgress = (DonutProgress) rootView.findViewById(R.id.remainingTimeIndicator);
Integer colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.donut_finished_color);
Integer colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.Red);
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
colorAnimation.setDuration(currentTimeLength);
long passedTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
colorAnimation.setCurrentPlayTime(passedTime);
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(final ValueAnimator animator) {

        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Integer colorValue = (Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue();
                remainingTimeProgress.setFinishedStrokeColor(colorValue);
            }
        });
    }

});
colorAnimation.start();
```

Here is my custom View code: http://pastebin.com/ERyLiczg

How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

I have experimented with some hard coded values for animation time like:

```
colorAnimation.setDuration(15000);
colorAnimation.setCurrentPlayTime(0);
```

And it has worked. But when I set the play time dynamically to passed time it doesn't change the color to color that should be at that time.

Do you have any idea what is the problem?

**UPDATE**

Setting current play time after start solved the problem.

```
colorAnimation.start();
colorAnimation.setCurrentPlayTime(passedTime);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call set current play time after start:

```
colorAnimation.start();
colorAnimation.setCurrentPlayTime(passedTime);
```